# How to force firefox to show mobile version of websites?

Tags: firefox, browser, websites

I have a [GPD Pocket](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/gpd-pocket-7-0-umpc-laptop-ubuntu-or-win-10-os-laptop--2) running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)) and [Firefox Quantum](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/). The GPD pocket is a small netbook (7 inch display). For some sites I would therefore prefer seeing on this screen the mobile version of the website (mainly on my work's [egroupware](http://www.egroupware.org/en/) server).

How is this possible?

Bonus question (but neither necessary nor sufficient to get the accepted answer): How to do this on Google Chrome/chromium?

I do not care if this is a per website or a global setting as I use different firefox profiles for different things.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Firefox

Showing the mobile version of websites is a built-in feature in Firefox. In Firefox select *Tools* -> *Web Developer* -> *Responsive Design Mode* and then from the dropdown menu select your device model.

#### Chromium / Chrome

Toggle the **Device Mode** button to turn Device Mode on or off. When Device Mode is on, the icon is blue ([image: IMG:]). When Device Mode is off, the icon is gray ([image: IMG:]). Select *Tools* -> *Developer tools* -> click *Toogle device toolbar* button (marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot -> click the black downward triangle ▾ to the right of "Responsive" to show the dropdown menu and select your device from the dropdown menu.

[image]

Comment: Thank you . One small question. What is DPR and how should I calculate it for my Device?

Comment: DPR stands for **D**evice **P**ixel **R**atio. To set a custom device pixel ratio, enter Responsive Design Mode in Firefox, click the list box labeled "DPR", and select the value you want. To get more fine-grained control over the DPR enter Responsive Design Mode, in the device list box select "no device selected",  change the zoom ratio in Firefox for the tab that has the focus by selecting *View* -> *Zoom* -> *Zoom In/Out* which will change the value of the currently selected DPR in the DPR list box.

Comment: When you change the device in Responsive Design Mode from the dropdown menu it automatically changes the DPR to the DPR that corresponds to the selected device. You can also edit the dropdown menu and create a custom device that has its own custom values for screen size and DPR.

Answer (score 6):

You may use an add-on like [User-Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher-revived/).

It lets you choose from many options:

[image]
(screenshot source: link above)

Comment: +1 This works thank you. I will accept @Karel 's solution as it is less invasive.

Comment: @Bruni I would have done the same too :-D

Comment: [List](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=useragent) of user agent switcher addons.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try substituting m for www in the url or a suitable Firefox addon such as Temporary Mobile View.